# Chrome on Android random red HTTPS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When I'm using Chrome on my desktop, the address bar is always green. However, on my Android phone the address bar is usually green, but sometimes red. It says that I'm using a certificate signed using a SHA1 signature in my certificate chain.

This happens very random, without any changes to my server's configuration. It also disappears without any change to my server's configuration, sometimes after a few minutes, sometimes after a few days.

I guess it has something to do with StartCom's root certificate, which is cross-signed using SHA256 and SHA1. Using [Qualys SSL Labs (report)](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=u5r.nl) I see that one chain contains a root certificate signed using SHA1. However, as this is the root certificate, I'm not able to change that.

[Screenshot when address bar in Chrome on Android is green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiJlN.png)
(I don't have a screenshot when the address bar is red, I'll add that if it happens again any time soon).

Is there any way to solve this? Why does Android sometimes seem to prefer the weaker SHA1 signed certificate over the SHA256 certificate? I'm using Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this in many devices, laptops, workstations, and servers. Even though there are many reasons for this. Two of the most common problems I found that fixes the issue is checking time synchronization in the system clock. It can report the wrong time compared to location issuing and invalidate verification. Reason why is because when clocks becomes unsynchronized with location. It shows an extended amount of time in acknowledgment. Causing the system to register a possible intrusion when in most cases it is the clock. After resetting the clock and everything goes to normal. If the error reappears. Then I would suggest  changing the system battery because it is no longer keeping enough charge to keep clock synchronization. Chrome browser is the first sign when synchronization is off. It is more sensitive to time changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem on one site also using a certificate from StartCom. In my case the problem turned out to be that I had forgotten to download a new version of [sub.class1.server.ca.pem](http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem) when renewing our certificate.

Here is a listing from a directory containing both the old and the current version:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2090 Feb  4  2015 sub.class1.server.ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2212 Apr 18  2010 sub.class1.server.ca.pem.old
```

The old version, which I had downloaded a year earlier, still worked in some browsers but not all.

Such a problem may appear to be sporadic due to caching. Some browsers cache intermediate certificates. If the browser has recently visited a site, which has been using the correct intermediate certificates, then the certificates may be cached. In this case a misconfigured site, which is missing those intermediate certificates, may appear to be working.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be enough information available to address what may cause the validation to fail occasionally. (Information about what actually fails would probably be helpful.)

However, regarding the question at the very end about preferring one of the two chains (the one you describe as weaker) over the other, there's at least some things that can be straightened out.

Regarding these two chains, both with SHA256-based signatures except for the root certificates where one chain has a root with a SHA1-based signature while the other one has a root with a SHA256-based signature, it's important to note that the signature algorithm of a root certificate is essentially irrelevant.

The root certificates are self-signed and clients trust these certificates based on having them available in their list of trusted certificates, not based on these certificates being signed by some other party.

Ie, the claim that one chain is weaker than the other seems to be unfounded (same length RSA keys, same signing algorithms other than the root).

Comment: This is exactly my problem. The only thing I can see on Chrome on Android is that a certificate in my chain uses SHA1, but I know my server only provides SHA256 certificates. As this is on my phone, I can't really get more information than that. This only happens on my phone. I was thinking that, because both root certificates have the same key, Android sometimes uses the wrong certificate.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen I don't see why it would care about the signature algorithm of a root certificate, though.  I still hope that whatever information is visible when validation fails would include some hint as to what the actual problem is. (Both root certificates have the same key? Are you positive?)